# Why does Okabe assume that Mayuri's death won't occur in the beta world line?

Tags: steins-gate

There's a question about [whether Mayuri can be saved in the alpha world line](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20128/35679), but because her death is so impossible to avoid there, it may also be impossible to avoid in the beta world line. How can Okabe know for sure that Mayuri won't just die a couple of days later than in the alpha line?